# Rails - can't convert Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash as follows:

```
display_helpers => { :helper_1 => { :helper => lambda { d.is_master_account? }, :text => "Master Account" } }
```

I also have an array with contents:

```
a => [ :helper_1, :other_symbol ]
```

I am trying to print the value of :text from within the hash as follows:

```
<%= display_helpers[ a[0] [ :text ] ] %>
```

When doing this, I keep getting the error "can't convert Symbol into Integer".

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little dizzy looking at this, but I think it should be this:

```
<%= display_helpers[ a[0] ] [ :text ]  %>
```